# Schengen visa for someone banned in the UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I am an Indian citizen who was working in the UK on a SEGS (post-study) visa. My HSMP visa was denied as the UKBA was unable to verify the IT Returns document. The time taken for the decision was well over 1 year. Leave to Remain/Variation of Leave (LTR) was automatically rejected, as I did not have a passport with a valid visa, as it lapsed due to the time taken for decision.

I appealed against this decision and voluntarily returned to India at my own expense. My appeal request was approved for HSMP, and I made an application for LTR from India, and this application was refused.

An administrative review request against this decision was refused under paragraphs 320 (7a) and (7b), and all future application are being refused for the next 10 years.

It's been over 5 years now, and I would like to see if I stand any chance of receiving a visa from any EU nation/non-EU nation. If I disclose my rejection details proactively to any other country that I wish to apply for business/work/visit visa, will the 10-year UK ban pose any issue?

Has anyone gone through a similar situation, and are there any general grounds of refusals like the UK has in other EU countries?

Comment: It is better to disclose rather than hide. Many EU countries share such information and it would surely flag up for your case. Check this page for more information http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system/index_en.htm  But I don't see any mention of any of this in the Schengen visa application form.

Comment: This question would seem to be appropriate at Expatraites.SE *as well*?  By no means am I discouraging this from being posted to Travel.SE as it would be useful here too?

Answer (score 4):

EU, UK, USA, Canada, Australia and a lot of other countries now share information in real time. If you lie in your application form you will most likely be refused for anything you apply for.

You are not banned by the UK, It is just that you cannot apply for the next 10 years of which 5 years as you say have gone by. This should not be looked upon as a ban on entry. From what I understand you can still apply for other types of visas but lying about the refusals is not an option in any case.

Comment: That is not correct, the information is not shared in real time and is limited. _The HVDS Data Sharing Protocol between the five member countries allows for the sharing of fingerprints from up to 3,000 people per country per year. This information can be used in immigration and identity cases for decisions about immigration and deportation._ http://www.biometricupdate.com/201409/what-is-biometric-data-sharing-an-introduction-overview

Answer (score -1):

You are banned only for UK, you can apply for Schengen countries but be careful for USA, Canada, Australia, New Zealand and Ireland.

But do it quickly as data sharing is going fast within countries.

Comment: Do you have any sources or references to back this up?

Comment: Yeah, why would that stop someone going to NZ?